# Get formated date from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How can i get a nicely well formated date from an unix timestamp?

For example i´m getting this unix timestamp value (today´s day) - 1401537600

How can i have it formatted in this way - Sat 31 May 2014 - ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Have you checked the JS `Date` class?

Comment: i don´t now nothing about dates classes!! :(

Comment: I did not really understand what you mean. Do you want to display the unix in the requested format in unix or javascript? Which OS do you use?

Comment: I need to convert unix timestamp to a readable date. I´m using windows.

Comment: You might want to look at the Moment.js library, it has a formatting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to do that. First get an instance by calling the constructor that accepts milliseconds:

```
var timestamp = 1401537600;
var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

Then, you can use a number of methods on the object to get a formatted representation of this date such as `d.toLocaleDateString()` or `d.toLocaleFormat(...)`.

Comment: You are right, There is no constructor like that. I deleted my answer.