# Count down timer not working properly when using server date in JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a countdown counter. The below code is working fine if I use JS date/time which is coming from the user's machine. I want to change it to take the date/time from the server. The problem that when I use PHP date in the JS code, the count down timer doesn't count unless I refresh the page.

The following is the php for the current date/time :

```
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

And then here I'm adding $date to a JS function :

```
var DownDate = new Date("Feb 5, 2050 23:50:00").getTime();
var ax = setInterval(function() {
//var anow = new Date().getTime(); // JS date will work fine, but I don't want to rely on user's machine time. So next is the same but using php date/time.

var anow = new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>").getTime();
var adistance = DownDate - anow;
var aminutes = Math.floor((adistance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var aseconds = Math.floor((adistance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 
   aminutes + "m " + aseconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If you're passing a timestamp to the browser to be parsed by the built–in parser, you should use one of the formats specified in ECMA-262. By far the most compatible timestamp is a time value in milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch, also called a "UNIX timestamp". UNIX timestamps are usually in seconds, so just multiply by 1,000 to get milliseconds. See [*Get formated date from unix timestamp*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968712/get-formated-date-from-unix-timestamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP code only gets executed on the server, you can't execute the php code in a loop in set interval, that's where your problem is.

Instead, execute it once and store it into a variable then let the client update the variable (and the dom) every time a second passes.

```
var DownDate = new Date("Feb 5, 2050 23:50:00").getTime();
var anow = new Date("<?php echo $date; ?>").getTime();
var ax = setInterval(function() {
    anow+= 1000
    var adistance = DownDate - anow;
    var aminutes = Math.floor((adistance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var aseconds = Math.floor((adistance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 
    aminutes + "m " + aseconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. please provide more code.

Comment: No problem, best of luck @v4valve